# Which is a subring? Which is an ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

We are having ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$.
Which of the sets is subrings of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$ and which are ideals?

1. $\mathbb{Z}+5\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$
2. $5\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$
3. $2\mathbb{Z}+3\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$

I know that if the ring is ideal of some set, then it is automatically a subring of this set, but that works only one way. If we have a subring, we can't say that it is an ideal.

To prove that a subring is an ideal we must present for example element from first set as $a+5b\sqrt{-6}$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and multiply it on similar representation of  $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$: it will be $a+b\sqrt{-6}$. And then if result $\in \mathbb{Z}+5\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$ we can say that it is an ideal.

Am I doing right way? And can you help me with proving that set is subring? (What should we say, to prove that set is subring).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that a set $I\subset R$ is an ideal, you must take an element $x$ from $I$ and an element $r$ from $R$ and prove that $x\cdot r$ is still an element of $I$. For example, for your first example, take $a+5b\sqrt{-6}$ from the "ideal" and $c+d\sqrt{-6}$ from the ring. Multiply the two to get $(ac - 30bd) + (5bc + ad)\sqrt{-6}$. Is this an element of $\mathbb Z + 5\mathbb Z [\sqrt{-6}]$ or can you find a counterexample where this does not hold?

Comment: Proving ideals quite clear for me. It will not be ideal, but it is subring. Which statements should we prove, to show ring is a subring? It seems the 2-nd ring not close by "*" operation. Is it enough to show that subring closed by '+' and '-' or we should prove some another statements?

Comment: To prove that a set $K\subset R$ is a subring, you must prove that it is closed both under multiplication and adition and that it contains aditive inverses, so for $x,y\in K$, you must show that $-x, x+y$ and $xy$ are all elements of $K$.

Comment: @5xum Also closure under addition should be proved; in the given sets it is almost obvious, but nonetheless noting this is important.